# Given a differentiable function f, such that the derivative is bounded on some interval. Show f is uniformly continuous. Also, is the converse true?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a feeling that I will be using the fact that if a function is differentiable on some interval, then it is continuous on that interval.  But I am confused on the details.

Comment: The fact you mention (continuous on a interval implying uniformly continuous) is only true for *closed* intervals; it does not hold for arbitrary ones. Indeed, consider for example the fact that $\mathbb R$ is an interval.

Comment: closed and bounded!

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, given $x < y$ in the interval and a bound $M$ on the derivative,

\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(y)| &= \left|\int_x^y f'(t) dt\right| \\
&\le \int_x^y |f'(t)| dt \\
&\le \int_x^y M dt \\
&= (y - x) M
\end{align*}

Can you use this to finish the proof?

---

For the converse, think about this: Does continuity (or even uniform continuity) imply the function is differentiable *anywhere*?

Answer (score 0):

T. Bongers did a fine job with the first part.

A counterexample for the second part:

Note that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ has an unbounded derivative on the interval $(0,1)$ but is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $0<r<1$ to be fixed later.

Assume that $|f'(x)| \le M$. Then via the mean value theorem,
$$
|x-y|\le r\implies |f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(c_{x,y})||x-y|\le M|x-y|\le Mr\le \epsilon
$$as soon as $r = \epsilon / M>0$. Hence the function us uniformly continuous.